# Set the return value of Meteor JS Helper, inject this dynamically into template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

**EDIT:**

Given the answers below, using [Meteor Deps](http://manual.meteor.com/#deps) seems like the ideal play since I want to share data between two distinct templates, and it should be reactive to any changes that occur.

To clarify: source of my data is `Template.reactiveTable` and the destination is `Template.buttons`.  When the data in `reactiveTable` changes, I want the buttons to reflect this.

**END EDIT**

I am looking to set the value of `buttons` based on the content of a table (specifically, the `<h1>` values).

buttons.html:

```
  <template name="buttons">
    {{#each testButtons }}
       <button id="{{ name }}">{{ name }}</button>
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

With this hard-coded it works as expected (two buttons render labeled Alice and Bob

```
UI.registerHelper('testButtons', function () {
        return [ 
          { name: "Alice" }, 
          { name: "Bob" } 
        ]
    }
)
```

The template happily accepts and renders this **array of objects**. However, NOT when I generate the array of objects dynamically.

**Goal:** for each unique word contained within my h1 tags, generate a button (almost like a blog tags).

By replacing my helper code with snippet below (using jquery parsing `<h1>` tags, generate array to send to template).

Assume html is:

```
  <h1>foo</h1>
  <h1>bar</h1>
  <h1>baz</h1>
```

then run snippet below in console, will create `uniqStrings = [ "foo", "bar", "baz"];` as desired.

```
$( 'h1' ).map(function () {
  var words = [];
  words.push($(this).text());
  uniqStrings = _.uniq(words);

});
```

How do I then send `uniqStrings` back to my buttons template to render `n= uniqStrings.length` buttons?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this html:

```
<body>
  <h1>Alice</h1>
  <h1>Bob</h1>
  {{> buttons}}
</body>

<template name="buttons">
  {{#each testButtons }}
    <button id="{{ name }}">{{ name }}</button>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

You can get it to work with this implementation:

```
Template.buttons.helpers({
  testButtons: function() {
    var words = UI._templateInstance().state.get('words');
    return _.map(words, function(word) {
      return {name: word};
    });
  }
});

Template.buttons.rendered = function() {
  var words = $('h1').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  });
  this.state.set('words', _.uniq(words));
};

Template.buttons.created = function() {
  this.state = new ReactiveDict;
};
```

**Note you will need to do: `meteor add reactive-dict`**

When the `buttons` template is created is initializes its own internal reactive state. After it is rendered, it fills that state with the text from all of the `h1` tags on the page. Because that state is reactive, it will then cause the `testButtons` to run and return the correctly formatted data to your template. Please see my post on [Scoped Reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) for more details.

Because the `buttons` template uses scoped reactivity, it can be used as many times as you like on any page without modification to the parent template.

Comment: Thanks David!  FWIW, I am working with two distinct templates: the h1 tags in Template.someTable, while buttons inside Template.buttons.  Not sure if this impacts the solution, but thanks for the solid answer.

Comment: This grabs the `h1` tags from all currently rendered templates, so it should work fine.

Comment: In my case the template has not yet been rendered and this is causing some problems with the solution.  How can I wait until TemplateName has been rendered before executing the above?

Comment: Unfortunately that violates a fundamental assumption in my answer. Frankly, everything about this question is unmeteorlike which I probably should have pointed out earlier. One possible answer (which I'll repost if it works for you) is to just use session variables. In your template(s) which render the `h1`s, set a session variable that says "I'm ready", or "the h1 text is..." then in this template just react to the session changes in your helper.

Comment: Create new Q that deals with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575845/reactive-meteor-templates-and-deps-dependency-update-a-template-when-another

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it's not totally clear to me why you're trying to parse the content of a table and then render it in another table (this is what you're trying to do, isn't it?), the basic principle is as follows:

Your template will rerender when any of its reactive dependencies change.  So that means that you need to either:

- store the array in question in a structure which is reactive by design (so either the [minimongo](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection), i.e the client side database), or else a [Session variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#session).
- use a separate (reactive) variable which just tells the template it needs to rerender at the right times.

The latter is probably less good from the perspective of app structure, but easiest to exemplify:

```
var renderDep = new Deps.Dependency(),
    words = [];

UI.registerHelper('testButtons', function () {
    renderDep.depend();
    return words;
});
```

And then whenever you call:

```
$( 'h1' ).map(function () {
    words = [];
    words.push($(this).text());
    uniqStrings = _.uniq(words);       
});
```

Make sure you call:

```
renderDep.changed();
```

immediately afterwards, and all its dependencies (i.e. the template helper) will rerun and return the new `words` content.

Comment: Thanks richsilv.  Regarding the first sentence: I am parsing a table and rendering buttons, rather than a new table.  I'll try our your suggestion, thanks again.