# Reactive Meteor Templates and Deps Dependency -- update a template when another changes or is re/rendered

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

**Problem**: Meteor JS app with 2 distinct templates that need to share some data.

They are dependent on one another, since I aim to **extract text (Step 1)** from one, and then **create dynamic buttons (Step 2)** in another template. The content of the buttons is dependent on the table.

buttons.html

```
<template name="buttons">

   {{#each dynamicButtons }}
    <button id="{{ name }}">{{ name }}</button>
  {{/each}}

</template>
```

My goal is for the **name** property to come from the content of reactiveTable.html (see above, or their [Github page](https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/reactive-table), package `meteor add aslagle:reactive-table`.

These need to be dynamically linked since table re-renders constantly w/ different group of products, which are linked up through `Template.reactiveTable` and a specific data context (Pub/Sub pattern).

IF the table is (re)rendered, then parse it's content and extract text.  Once the table is parsed, dynamically inject newly created buttons into the UI.  *Note UI.insert takes two arguments, the Object to insert, and then location (DOM node to render it in).*

```
Template.reactiveTable.rendered = function () {
    UI.insert( UI.render( Template.buttons ) , $('.reactive-table-filter').get(0) )
};
```

(Insert new buttons every time a reactiveTable is rendered.)

This code works, but is flawed since I cannot grab the newly rendered content from `reactiveTable.` As shown in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550593/set-the-return-value-of-meteor-js-helper-inject-this-dynamically-into-template/25551359?noredirect=1#comment39933293_25551359), using `ReactiveDict` package:

```
Template.buttons.helpers({
  dynamicButtons: function() {
    var words = UI._templateInstance().state.get('words');
    return _.map(words, function(word) {
      return {name: word};
    });
  }
});

Template.buttons.rendered = function() {

  // won't work w/ $('.reactiveTable) since table not rendered yet, BUT  
  // using $('h1') grabs content and successfully rendered dynamicButtons!

  var words = $('h1').map(function() { 
    return $(this).text();             
  });
  this.state.set('words', _.uniq(words));
};

Template.buttons.created = function() {
  this.state = new ReactiveDict;
};
```

How can I change my selector to extract content from Template.reactiveTable every time is re-renders to create buttons dynamically?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using a lot of undocumented functions in there, and `UI.insert` and `UI.render` which are bad practice. The just-released Meteor 0.9.1 eliminates them, in fact.

Create your dynamic buttons the Meteoric way: by making them dependent on a reactive resource. For example, a Session variable. (You could also use a client-side-only collection if you want.)

```
Template.reactiveTable.rendered = function () {
  // Get words from wherever that data comes from
  Session.set('buttons', words);
};

Template.buttons.helpers({
  dynamicButtons: function() {
    if (Session.equals('buttons', null))
      return [];
    else
      return _.map(Session.get('buttons'), function(word) {
        return {name: word};
      });
  }
});
```

Every time `reactiveTable` is rendered or rerendered, the `buttons` Session variable will update. And because your dynamic buttons are depending on it, and since Session variables are a reactive resource, the buttons will rerender automatically to reflect the changes.